# Flash , PHP CMS

Tags: php, flash, content-management-system

Does any one know of an article's on the element's / structure needed to create a flash , php , MySQL cms ?

I failed to mention flash would be the GUI for the CMS

Comment: That is about as specific as "does anybody know how to build a car?" you may want to go more into detail about what you want to do, and especially what role Flash exactly plays in it.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim to produce a flash website with a php backend cms, then any cms will do (e.g. Joomla, Drupal), as long as your output templates do not create html files, but xml and then load these xml files in flash, which will do the presentation.

That way you can easily create a flash and a non-flash version for all those mobile browsers.

Comment: I have already created something like that. I was thinking of a flash GUI for the Admin area of the CMS